# Imputation in R: How to impute univariate data in R?

Tags: r, missing-data, data-imputation

I am trying classification(2 classes) using Random Forest. Classes are - Red, Green. My dataset contains 1 numeric attributes(called X), and 51 binary attributes to classify a document into red and green classes. However, 40% of the data points(observations) do not have value for numeric attribute X i.e. X is missing. Hence, trying to impute X. I tried using MI, MICE, and other variants(Hmisc, impute). But I did not find them working.

Is it possible to impute when 40% of the data points are missing? How can one impute an attribute based on its class specific data points? Hmisc allows to use median, min, max etc - however, it is not class specific median - it imputes column wise median in NA's.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You will need to clarify much. Is classify(2) a function? Is this in the random forest package? What are you classifying? Some construct based on the 51 attributes? Or are you trying to predict blood pressure. You refer to "instances" but are "instances" variables (columns, attributes, or features) or observations (rows, persons, or samples) in the dataset? When you say "40% do not have numeric data" do you mean to say  40% of the data are missing? Please edit your question.

Comment: You also refer to classes. You need to define what a class is.\

Comment: Perhaps most importantly: what exactly does "But I did not find them working" mean? Couldn't figure out how to run? Got error messages? Worked badly when run?

Comment: I could not find the approach to impute univariate missing values. MI takes longer running time(1600 observations, 40% missing value), but never returns a result. I am looking for an example on univariate imputation.

Comment: If you have classes and some other data points you are not asking about univariate but about **bivariate** method. Univariate imputation with median is basically `myvec[is.na(myvec] <- median(myvec, na.rm = TRUE)`...

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset has a time series character you can have a look at 
this paper comparing methods for univariate time series imputation in R: http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03924

But actually I guess you caption is misleading, usually you speak of univariate data if you have just one attribute

What I understood is, you have 52 attributes (1 numeric, 51 binary).
So you do not need special algorithms for univariate imputation.
The MICE package should be alright for this task. (even with 40% missing data)
Perhaps you can post your MICE code, that we see what is going wrong.